# Java JRE fatal error: too many multiplications

Tags: java

I was trying to test speed of `Math.pow()` against multiplication "by hand" and stumbled upon this error:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005ac46888, pid=1508, tid=6016
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
>   Problematic frame:
>   V  [jvm.dll+0x496888]
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

Code generating it:

```
long t = System.nanoTime();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    double val = i*i*i*i*i /* 256 times *i */ *i*i*i;
    sum ^= Double.doubleToLongBits(val);
}
System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - t) / 10000000);
```

I get that this is really extreme case, but still, this is valid code and the worst thing that could happen should be having Inf in the value, and not JRE crash. Is this really standard behaviour described by oracle or just bug nobody wants to fix just because if you are seeing it, you are really bad person.

For the record run with NetBeans 8.0.2

**UPDATE 1**

It seems problem is in magnitude of multiplied number.

```
long t = System.nanoTime();
for(int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++) {
    int i = j % 50;
    double val = i*i*i*i*i /* 256 times *i */ *i*i*i;
    sum ^= Double.doubleToLongBits(val);
}
System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - t) / 10000000);
```

will pass just fine.

**UPDATE 2**

Tried to run it from console with

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

and passed just fine, so I assume it must be either issue with this specific JRE or with NetBeans.

Comment: The JRE version would be useful. I tried running this on Oracle 1.8.0_45-b15 (64 bit) and it worked fine.

Comment: With binary search, I've determined that multiplying 124 `i`s works, but 125 gives the error above, at least on my Windows 7 PC, running Java 1.8.0_45, through IntelliJ.

Comment: And if you compile the code with plain `javac` and run it from the command line?

Comment: version of compiler and JRE is in third line of the log ( (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18) ) or isn't it?

Comment: @biziclop When compiling and running from the command line, 241 `i`s runs fine, but 242 gives the error.

Comment: It seems to be issue with JRE 8.0_25 my NetBeans are using, since code compiled by JDK 8.0_25 run by JRE 8.0_45 passes just fine.

Comment: And it seems to be only an issue with the amd64 libs, as I've tried with the exact same build and it worked fine.

Comment: Netbeans has no connection to the issue. Netbeans simply makes it easy to run your program in the JVM that you ask it to use.

Comment: Looks like bug in JRE 8.0_25 that has been fixed somewhere until 8.0_45

Comment: You will never get `Inf` in the value. These are integer multiplications. You will just get integer overflow and an integer result of the multiplication, then a conversion to double. This code isn't comparable to `Math.pow()` in any way. Shouldn't fail, but it doesn't do what you want. I don't get the `sum ^=` part either.

Comment: @EJP I hear compilers like to throw away useless code and XOR with print are really cheap way to ensure that doesn't happen. Of course I'm not 100% sure it could happen in this case in any compiler, but it already happened to me with different code. If compiler sees contents of your variable do not leave the scope or are passed somehow outside of it, it may start removing operations that are done over it.

As for pow comparison, realized later that double and int multiplications aren't exactly comparable. What I was trying to test was inefficiency of Math.pow(int,+int).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely looks like a JVM bug to me. This is more suitable as a bug report than a question on SO. See http://bugreport.java.com/

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.
Where does the problem occur for you?  Isolate the problem by reducing the multiplications or number of loops.  Does it work with 50 multiplications?

```
long sum=0;
long t = System.nanoTime();
for (int i = 1; i < 10000000; i++) {
    double val = i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i
                    *i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i
                    *i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i; 
            // set of 10 *i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i*i
    sum ^= Double.doubleToLongBits(val);
}
System.out.println(sum);
System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - t) / 10000000);
```

jre1.8.0_51

output:

```
    -32067153335156736
    614
```

Even multiplying by 10 more iterations works but is really slow.  time 6020

Comment: In comments under the question we concluded it happens on JRE 8.0_25 and number of multiplications varying.

Answer (score 0):

Try using BigInteger.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class hackerrank {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        BigInteger x = new BigInteger("10000000");
        BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
        long t = System.nanoTime();
        for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE; i.compareTo(x) == -1; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            BigInteger j = i.remainder(new BigInteger("50"));
            BigInteger val = j.pow(256);
            sum = sum.xor(val);
        }
        System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - t) / 10000000);
    }
}
```

Output: 4083

Comment: You completely missed the point of this question. It is not about getting the answer to original task, rather that finding out why completely valid code is crashing the JVM. Besides, measuring on BigInteger does not follow with the thing I was checking, that is, from what point it is no longer beneficial avoiding "Math.pow" by expanding the multiplication. I suppose BigInteger isn't exactly your every day number type.